# Trying to find the average amount of attempt it takes for Tom to roll a six on: 10 repetitions

Tags: c#, for-loop, average, dice

It takes the total number of rolls and divides them by 10. For example, if it took 56 rolls so my average is 5.6.

```
        Random numGen = new Random ();

        int numOfAttempt = 0;
        int Attempt = 0;
        int avrBefore = 0;
        int avrAfter = 0;


        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)

            do {

                Attempt = numGen.Next (1, 7);
                Console.WriteLine (Attempt);
                numOfAttempt++;
                avrBefore = numOfAttempt;
                avrAfter = avrBefore / 10;

            } while (Attempt != 6); 

        Console.WriteLine ("He tried " + numOfAttempt + " times to roll a six.");
        Console.WriteLine ("The average number of times it took to get a six was " + avrAfter);
        Console.ReadKey ();
```

Comment: You seem to be missing an = in avrBefore + numOfAttempt;

Comment: Right sorry I copied the code over wrong.  "avrBefore = numOfAttempt;"      Before I had it set as avrBefore = avrBefore + numOfAttempt; But that gave me way to high numbers as the average.

Comment: You shouldn't be diving by ten at the point you are. That's for the average across your 10 attempts, but you output avrAfter even after a single attempt.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that, I've only started learning recently by watch Brackey's C# for beginners. This is the last challenge he gave during the series but he never posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to reset the vars inside the for loop, before the while:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    int numOfAttempt = 0;
    int Attempt = 0;
    int avrBefore = 0;
    int avrAfter = 0;

        do {//your code
```

Comment: That seems to give me an error: Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labelled statement

Comment: this error use to happens if you have an error in your loops, check it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know how many times it took to get a six. This is quite simple. You just have to save how many times you rolled the dices and how many times you got a six.

```
Random numGen = new Random ();

int attempt = 0;
int numOfAttempt = 0;
int numberOfSixes = 0;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    do {
        attempt = numGen.Next (1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine (Attempt);
        numOfAttempt++;
    } while (Attempt != 6); 
    numberOfSixes++;
}
Console.WriteLine ("He tried " + numOfAttempt + " times to roll a  six.");
Console.WriteLine ("The average number of times it took to get a six was " + (numberOfAttempt/numberOfSixes));
Console.ReadKey ();
```

I hope you understand my approach.

I would appreciate it if you could elaborate your thought process behind avrBefore,avrAfter and divide by 10. I didn't get that.

Comment: This is a c# question so I'm not sure why you mention C11.

Comment: I didnt see that c# tag. Sorry for that

Comment: My thought process with that was pretty mediocre, I thought since I was doing 10 repetition I would divide by 10. Yeah writing it out again like this, I ask myself what was I thinking.

Comment: This loops 9 times (0 to 8).

Answer (score 0):

You are diving by ten at the wrong time.

You are dividing by ten even when you haven't done ten iterations.

This code below instead shows the correct average at each iteration.

```
void Main()
{
    Random numGen = new Random ();

    int totalAttempts = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {

        int attempts = 0;
        int attempt  = 0;
        do {
            attempt = numGen.Next (1, 7);
            attempts++;
        } while (attempt != 6); 

        totalAttempts+=attempts;
        Console.WriteLine ("He tried " + attempts + " times to roll a six.");
        Console.WriteLine ("The average number of times it took to get a six was " + (double)totalAttempts / i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for your help, Out of all the responses here I think your was the best. "This doesn't mean everyone else was unhelpful cause you all were thank-you" When I tried moving all the variables to the top, the code only ran one time. Why do you think that is?

Comment: Did you move attempt outside the for loop? If so then once it was set to 6 it would no longer enter the while loop if you didn't reset it back to 0 inside the for loop.

Comment: Yeah I move both  int attempts = 0; int attempt  = 0; outside of the for loop. Interesting that it does that.

Comment: @DavidLamonaca - It's **not** a good idea to declare your variables at the top of a method - that's old thinking based on older programming languages. It is best to declare them as late as possible in your code as this aids clarity, refactoring, and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten down the code a lot and get it correct:

```
        Random numGen = new Random();
        int numOfAttempt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int attempt = 0;
            while (attempt != 6)
            {
                attempt = numGen.Next(1, 7);
                Console.WriteLine (attempt );
                numOfAttempt++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("He tried " + numOfAttempt + " times to roll a six.");
        Console.WriteLine("The average number of times it took to get a six was " + numOfAttempt / 10.0);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Technically this is different output because it only writes out the attempts once rather than after each 6 is rolled. It would say something like "He tried 78 times to roll a six." which may not be what is desired.